# Autorize users in a multiple layer prefix

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp to build a new website and for the admin part, I am using multi layer prefixes, for ex. (admin/web)

So in this case admin is a prefix and web is a prefix.

I have been trying to use authorize => controller and setup the isAuthorized function like the following:

```
public function isAuthorized($user = null)
    {
        if (!$this->request->getParam('prefix')) {
            return true;
        }
        // Only admins or specific roles can access admin functions
        if ($this->request->getParam('prefix') === 'admin') {
            if ($this->request->getParam('prefix') === 'web') {
                 return (bool)($user['role'] === 'admin');
            }
            return (bool)($user['role'] === 'admin');
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And in any controller I added:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) 
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
}
```

But only the first prefix (admin) is working, the other (web), gives me a message, saying I need to login before I can see that page.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: How can the prefix by both at the same time? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: @mark what do you mean?

Comment: If you mean to have 2 prefixes at the same time, according to the documentation, that is possible. You can have an "admin" prefix to cover the general admin part and an extra layer, in this case "web": https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Comment: Yeah, but your code is bad. `$this->request->getParam('prefix')` cannot return both admin and web at the same time, it is only possible in quantum physics.

Comment: ok, understand, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Check the return type of that key, maybe it is an array? Otherwise, you need to find a different approach. My recommendation: Do not use nesting, use separate prefixing, then all works quite nicely with less trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) says, you can move "admin" actions under admin scope:

```php
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    // All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin`
    // And have the prefix => admin route element added.
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

and place your admin methods under lets say
`src/Controller/Admin/UsersController.php`

Or you can use both prefixes how it is now, lets say: `page/admin/web/page`
but in this case

```php
 // $this->request->getParam('prefix') returns admin/web
public function isAuthorized($user = null)
    {
        $prefix =$this->request->getParam('prefix');
        if (!$prefix ) {
            return true; //sure?
        }
        // Only admins or specific roles can access admin functions
        if ($prefix==='web/admin' || $prefix==='admin') {
            return (bool)($user['role'] === 'admin');
        }
        return false;
    }
```